# How is log base 10 related to the Natural Logarithm

Tags: logarithms

Log base 4 (7) can be evaluated using the change of base formula. This can similarly be expressed as ln7 divided by ln4, using the natural logarithm.

Using the above example,

Why is it that these two ratios are equal, but log base 10 (7) is not equal to ln 7?

More generally, why can the log base 10 (x) be replaced in the change of base calculation with lnx?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  As you remark, the change of base formula lets us pass from one log to another.  This doesn't mean that the logs are all the same, of course, just that it is easy to get from one to the other.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @NoChance I do not follow your comment...  $\ln(7)/\ln(4) =\log_4(7)\approx 1.4037$.  Where did you get $0.5596\dots$ from?  The change of basis formula is well known and I even give a proof for it below... there is no reason to suggest that the change of basis formula is incorrect.

Comment: @JMoravitz I did not suggest that the change base formula is incorrect at all. The OP made a claim. I showed by numbers that his claim is not correct. Also, I published this comment before your proof.

Comment: @NoChance What claim? and why did you write $\ln(7)/\ln(4)=0.5596\dots$ (*which is incorrect*)?  What calculation led you to the value of $0.5596\dots$?

Comment: @JMoravitz I see what you mean I should have written 1.40367746103 instead. OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that:

$$\log_a(x) = \dfrac{\log_b(x)}{\log_b(a)}$$ for all positive real values of $b$ different than $1$.  In particular when $b=10$ or when $b=e$.

To see this... suppose that $\log_a(x)=y$.

Then you have $x=a^y$.

Now, take the logarithm base $b$ of both sides to get $\log_b(x)=\log_b(a^y)$ which by logarithm rules the exponent can drop outside as $\log_b(x)=y\log_b(a)$

Now, dividing you get $y=\dfrac{\log_b(x)}{\log_b(a)}$ which remembering that $y=\log_a(x)$ gives the identity given at the start.

---

If your question really was why $\log_{10} 7 \neq \log_e 7$, that should be obvious since $10\neq e$

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that:
$$
10\approx\operatorname{e}^{2.3}
$$
and therefore $\operatorname{e}$ has to be raised to approximately $2.3$ times as high a power as does $10$ in order to yield the same result. Hence:
$$
\ln(x)\approx2.3\log_{10}(x)
$$
and so:
$$
\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(b)}=\frac{2.3\log_{10}(a)}{2.3\log_{10}(b)}
$$
and the common factor $\ln(10)\approx2.3$ cancels out.